# Activating sef plugin throws a 404 error

Tags: joomla-2.5, sef, .htaccess-configuration

A joomla website is throwing a `404 error`, when I try to access it root page `/index.php`, but when I `deactivate` the joomla built-in `sef plugin`,
the website is accessed normally (`code 200`).
I have tried to clear my `.htaccess` but the error persists.
I wonder if I have to change anything in my `sef plugin` code?

I have also some strange redirection on the `/administrator` page when I change some `configuration & save`, the page redirected to have `'http'`
just after host name: `http://hostname/httpadministrator`. But because the redirection is not coming from my .htaccess I cant debug it with `RewriteLog`.

I'm suspecting the `sef builtin plugin``. Does anyone know what can be the source of this issue?

**P.S:**
I'm using Joomla 2.5 with K2.

Comment: you should really ask your host because they will know your environment and hardware and if they are any good have had to figure this out tons of times already. It will be difficult for anyone to give you anything but shot-in-the-dark answers to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just the `browser proxy` that was redirecting to an ugly url that `joomla's` `router` couldnt translate.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you: http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_%28SEF%29_URLs

Try to comment out `Options +FollowSymLinks` in the htaccess file.

Comment: Commenting `Options +FollowSymLinks` hadnt resolved it.

Comment: And you follow the other instructions in the provided link?

Comment: Yep it hadnt resolved my problem. What I found strange is the `http` string concatenated to the url when I try to save inside the `/administrator`.

Comment: Who is the Webhoster? 99% of my own and client sites need only to rename the htaccess.txt to .htaccess and then comment out the rewritebase / setting and then to activate the sef settings in the joomla global configuration menu. Maybe this is a hoster problem.